# Broadcast Receiver error Null pointer expection

Tags: android, service, android-broadcastreceiver

In my Main Activity I have a broadcast Receiver

```
    public static class the_receive extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            if(extras.containsKey("retvalue")){
                test.setText(extras.get("retvalue").toString());
            }
        }
    }
};
```

and in my Android manifest

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".MainActivity$the_receive"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ax.androidexample.mybroadcast" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This works perfectly fine and receives incoming values.

However when I want another broadcast receive in another Activity

```
public static class b_receive extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            if(extras.containsKey("retvalue")){
                text.setText(extras.get("retvalue").toString());
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And in my Android Manifest

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".MainActivity$the_receive"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ax.androidexample.mybroadcast" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".testService$b_receive"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ax.androidexample.mybroadcast" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I start getting this error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

In my MainActivity

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you heaps

Comment: The error message means that the broadcast is being received when that Activity is dead and it's TextViews are no longer available.

Comment: I see,  how should i fix that? why would that Activity be dead? All i did was add one more line to Android Manifest :(

Comment: If you only want the Activity receive messages while it is resumed, you need to register the BroadcastReceiver programatically (not through the manifest).

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem, I added 
myReceiver = new b_receive();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("ax.androidexample.mybroadcast");
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);

Answer (score 1):

Consider registering and unregistering your receiver by overriding methods of the lifecycle of the activity or fragment you use your receiver in.

Activity Live Cycle here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Fragment Live Cycle here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

- You must unregister your receiver before your activity becomes
  inactive.
- You have to register it again when your activity becomes
  active.